# Reputable companies to manage AWS infastructure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, rackspace

I’m trying to choose where to host my rails app and I’m leaning towards AWS, but I was wondering if there are any reputable companies out there that will manage my infrastructure on AWS, similar to what Rackspace managed cloud option does.

In case you’re wondering why I don’t just host with Rackspace if I need someone else to manage my infrastructure, the reason is that I can’t justify the upfront cost. Rackspace charges $100 flat fee a month for infrastructure management plus the cost of using utilities which could easily run me close to $300/month for a small application whereas on AWS I could pretty much run the app (at least in the beginning) using their free tier. If I can find a reputable company that offers infrastructure management for a price comparable to what Rackspace charges ($100). I could have the best of both worlds.

Btw, managing the infrastructure myself at this point is not an option. I have zero knowledge on the subject. While I’m learning, I don’t have the time to wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered Platform-as-a-Service ?

[Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/), [Engine Yard](http://www.engineyard.com/) or [Cloud Foundry](http://www.cloudfoundry.com/) would allow you to deploy the app itself, without worrying about the infrastructure running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Also, take a look at [Scalr](http://scalr.net/)
[How it works](http://scalr.net/tour/)
[Pricing](http://scalr.net/pricing/)